# How can I change MIME extensions handled by Chrome plugins (note: plugins, not extensions)

Tags: google-chrome

I have a KDE "KParts" Chrome plugin, which lets me view PDFs in the browser (pretty handy when I'm viewing papers which may not be worth downloading). However, its handling of SVG images is not very good. Is there any way I can change the plugin to only work for specific MIME types? I didn't see any options in the `chrome://plugins` page.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I disabled the KParts plugin at `chrome://plugins` and I haven't missed it.  Chrome renders the SVGs well.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has its own *Integrated PDF Viwer*, when I click on links to online PDFs, they are opened by it. Just hovering over the bottom right corner of an opened PDF, pops a little toolbar with options to zoom, print, save, etc.

But to open local PDFs, what I do is manually edit my mime types so PDFs are opened by Chrome. I use Xfce and it has a nice mime editor. But by just right clicking  a PDF file on the file manager and choosing the `Open with` option, then selecting Chrome from the list and making sure the *Always use this application for this kind of files* is checked, I get the same results.

I'm sure KDE works in a similar fashion.

Finally you didn't want extensions mentioned but [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-pdfpowerpoint-viewer/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn), opens not just PDFs, but a plethora of other formats online, using Google docs viewers. It also opens online PDFs (In mi case, I have it not open PDFs, only some other formats)

Answer (score 0):

Googles Chrome/Chromium viewer technology has changed much over the years and PDF  / and HTML such as SVG are well supported. Thus their current recommendation for plug-ins is based **only** on extending for Office Formats as PDF is considered native.

> The "Docs **PDF**/PowerPoint Viewer" extension is now obsolete - we recommend trying Google's "Office Editing for Docs, Sheets & Slides" extension instead: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj

More specifically pertinent to OP question.

> **On the options page you can also disable any file formats you don't want to use the Viewer for.**

However there is no normal means to switch SVG on/off in the "standard" browser.